# Ubuntu 20.04 WiFi access point without subnet/DHCP server

Tags: networking, network-manager, network-bridge, wireless-access-point, hostapd

I have Mac Mini with Ubuntu 20.04 server installed (so no GUI).
And want to use it as a WiFi access point, without NAT/DHCP server (so, given that main Mikrotik router is 192.168.88.1, both Mac Mini and all wireless clients connected to it will be in 192.168.88.* network).

Installed `hostapd` and `br-utils`, edited `/etc/network/interfaces` and so on.
Without bridge `hostapd` works and let's phone to connect to WiFi (no internet yet of course). But when I add `bridge=br0` to the `hostapd.conf`, phone fails to connect to WiFi network, telling 'Invalid password'.

What I do wrong?

Configs are below:
`hostapd.conf`:

```
interface=wlp3s0b1
ssid=SomeSSID
wpa_passphrase=12345678
hw_mode=g
country_code=UA
channel=7
wpa=2
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
auth_algs=1
bridge=br0
```

`/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp2s0f0
allow-hotplug enp2s0f0
iface enp2s0f0 inet dhcp

auto wlp3s0b1
allow-hotplug wlp3s0b1
iface wlp3s0b1 inet dhcp

auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
bridge_ports enp2s0f0 wlp3s0b1
```

And kinda suspicious records in syslog, printed after the `hostapd` restart:

```
Feb 24 14:53:55 infmedia systemd[1]: Starting Advanced IEEE 802.11 AP and IEEE 802.1X/WPA/WPA2/EAP Authenticator...
Feb 24 14:53:55 infmedia hostapd[1278]: Configuration file: /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
Feb 24 14:53:55 infmedia kernel: [  610.311270] b43-phy0: Loading firmware version 666.2 (2011-02-23 01:15:07)
Feb 24 14:53:55 infmedia systemd-networkd[684]: wlp3s0b1: Link UP
Feb 24 14:53:55 infmedia systemd-networkd[684]: rtnl: received neighbor for link '6' we don't know about, ignoring.
Feb 24 14:53:55 infmedia kernel: [  610.487176] br0: port 1(wlp3s0b1) entered blocking state
Feb 24 14:53:55 infmedia kernel: [  610.487180] br0: port 1(wlp3s0b1) entered disabled state
Feb 24 14:53:55 infmedia kernel: [  610.487268] device wlp3s0b1 entered promiscuous mode
Feb 24 14:53:55 infmedia hostapd[1278]: wlp3s0b1: interface state UNINITIALIZED->COUNTRY_UPDATE
Feb 24 14:53:55 infmedia hostapd[1278]: Using interface wlp3s0b1 with hwaddr 7c:xx:xx:xx:xx:f9 and ssid "SomeSSID"
Feb 24 14:53:55 infmedia networkd-dispatcher[708]: WARNING:Unknown index 6 seen, reloading interface list
Feb 24 14:53:55 infmedia NetworkManager[700]: <info>  [1614178435.4982] manager: (br0): new Bridge device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/6)
Feb 24 14:53:55 infmedia systemd-udevd[1259]: Using default interface naming scheme 'v245'.
Feb 24 14:53:55 infmedia systemd-udevd[1259]: ethtool: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
Feb 24 14:53:55 infmedia systemd-udevd[1259]: br0: Could not generate persistent MAC: No data available
Feb 24 14:53:55 infmedia NetworkManager[700]: <info>  [1614178435.5038] device (wlp3s0b1): released from master device br0
Feb 24 14:53:55 infmedia kernel: [  610.523498] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp3s0b1: link becomes ready
Feb 24 14:53:55 infmedia systemd-networkd[684]: wlp3s0b1: Gained carrier
Feb 24 14:53:55 infmedia hostapd[1278]: wlp3s0b1: interface state COUNTRY_UPDATE->ENABLED
Feb 24 14:53:55 infmedia hostapd[1278]: wlp3s0b1: AP-ENABLED
Feb 24 14:53:55 infmedia systemd[1]: Started Advanced IEEE 802.11 AP and IEEE 802.1X/WPA/WPA2/EAP Authenticator.
Feb 24 14:53:57 infmedia systemd-networkd[684]: wlp3s0b1: Gained IPv6LL
```

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/1178977/269484 . should work with `SHARE_METHOD=bridge`

Comment: Thanks for the link. Unfortunately, `This project is no longer maintained.` and `I used SHARE_METHOD=nat because SHARE_METHOD=bridge gave me an error`.

Comment: The project is not maintained but i's still great and you can look at the source code. Regarding the SHARE _METHOD, probably os or kernel flag related. Maybe it will work on your device. If not you need to do some investigation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bug in Ubuntu 20.04 NetworkManager, were WPA/WPA2 gives password errors if used with bridge.

https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/-/issues/315